# xml regular expression string in notepad++.How to find a tag which is not inside a particular parent

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

I have XML tag in the following format

```
<saw:column columnID="c83" xsi:type="saw:regularColumn">            
<saw:displayFormat>
<saw:formatSpec visibility="hidden" suppress="default" interaction="default" wrapText="true"/>
</saw:displayFormat>            
<saw:columnHeading>               
<saw:displayFormat>
<saw:formatSpec interaction="default"/>
</saw:displayFormat>
</saw:columnHeading>
 <saw:columnFormula>
<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">max("Supply Fact"."Count")</sawx:expr></saw:columnFormula>
</saw:column>
```

I have to replace  the data inside the tag  `<saw:displayFormat></saw:displayFormat>`

The tag is present both inside the `<saw:column>` tag and is also a child of `<saw:columnHeading>`. I don't wanna replace the displayformat  tag inside columnHeading  but wanna replace display format tag under `saw:column`

I tried `<saw:displayFormat>.*?</saw:displayFormat>`. This fetches all  the display format tags .

How to omit  the ones inside `<saw:columnHeading>`?

Comment: don't try to parse xml files with regex...

Comment: As far as I can tell he's not trying to parse it, just a ponctual need to do replacement into a file...

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aI8oI2/1)

`(?<!<saw:columnHeading>).<saw:displayFormat>(.*?)<\/saw:displayFormat>.(?!<\/saw:columnHeading>)`

It should match your search without being surrounded by columHeading tags. 
There's a `.` to match the newline if needed before and after

Answer (score 0):

Though trying to parse xml with regexes is a bad idea, this works for me in Notepad++. It assumes though that there is nothing (including whitespace other than `\r\n`) between the `columnHeading` tag and the `displayFormat` tag.

```
(?<!<saw:columnHeading>\r\n)<saw:displayFormat>.*?</saw:displayFormat>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   (?!(?!.*?<saw:columnHeading>))<saw:displayFormat>(.*?)<\/saw:displayFormat>
```

This should do you work.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cN9bJ4/2